# Primary key error when copying table data in SQLLite

Tags: sqlite, copy, primary-key

I've created a second table that I want to copy data from a first table to.

table2 has the same structure as table1, only some of it's columns are COLLATE NOCASE. Apart from that and the table names, the tables are identical.

Each table has the PK:

```
hID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

When copying, I get an error on the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1
```

The error:

```
PRIMARY KEY must be unique
```

I'm assuming the original data is unique, as it's always had the PK.

I want to preserve the original hID's when copying ie I don't want new hID's set for the old data being copied.

In MySQL, I'd normally apply a PK to the second table AFTER copying over the data, but I think that's not allowed in SQLLite.

Can anyone explain the error in my ways?

Comment: table2 is definitely empty before you insert the table1 values into it? The tables have exactly the same structure (the same ordering of columns, too)?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your problem. Is `table2` empty before insert?

Comment: Also, why would you duplicate all data because of collation? Just create indexes with different collations for first table!

Comment: I'll check that the table really is empty, but re using indexes for different collations - that's what I originally did, but found the indexes where ignored in queries. Tested a new table with collations in the columns, and it worked. My index: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS authorIdx ON table1 (Author,Title,hID collate nocase). My query that ignores that index: SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Author COLLATE NOCASE ASC,Title COLLATE NOCASE ASC,hID COLLATE NOCASE ASC LIMIT 100. Also ignores it - SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Author, Title, hID LIMIT 100.

Comment: My index was incorrect - it was CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx ON table1 (Author,Title,hID COLLATE NOCASE) instead of CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx ON table1 (Author COLLATE NOCASE,Title COLLATE NOCASE,hID COLLATE NOCASE). So like LS_Lev said, I don't need to recreate the table, just create proper indexes. THANKS!

Comment: Is this resolved? If not, can you grep through the extant database to verify that each value of the PK column is indeed unique?

Comment: Hi duhaime. I can't remember what this was all about now. I'm assuming I resolved it mate.